# how to use load cursor in db2 to insert null entries for newly created definition of existing table

Tags: db2, database-cursor

i have a requirement where i had to modify the definition of the existing table (my_Table) by adding new columns in mid of the table.
I have taken backup of the table, dropped the existing one and created it with new definition.

Now i wanted to load all the old data from backup file to my newly modified table using cursor load so that all the other columns get populated with data from backup file and newly added columns have ' ' (blank ) in the table

How to achieve this in **DB2**

Comment: You should understand, that "cursor load" (the official Db2 term is "load from cursor") is based on the result of a SELECT statement, and you can't use SELECT against of files unless it's a CSV file, you are at Db2 v11.5 at least and you are going to use an external table to have an ability to construct SELECT reading this file. Why do you want to use namely `load from cursor` and not Db2 `import`, `load` or `ingest` commands to load data from this file?

Comment: Why do you think you need to add new columns "to the mid of the table", as distinct from just adding new columns?  Why do you think  order of columns matters in the table?